# Extract string from Given vector string in R

Tags: r

I want to extract city names from all the address given in the vector.
`address_list=c("802/hiranandani/Mumbai",
               "2A/kalka-Delhi",
               "345#near adyar#Chennai",
               "10-shyaam bazzar-Kolkata")`

I tried using strsplit(address_list, c("/","-","#","-"),) function. But it's not giving expected answer.
Final answer should be

```
## [1] "Mumbai"
## [1] "Delhi"
## [1] "Chennai"
## [1] "Kolkata"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `gsub`

```
> gsub(".*(\\b\\w+$)","\\1",address_list)
[1] "Mumbai"  "Delhi"   "Chennai" "Kolkata"
```

---

If you want to print each one, try

```
> for (i in gsub(".*(\\b\\w+$)","\\1",address_list)) print(i)
[1] "Mumbai"
[1] "Delhi"
[1] "Chennai"
[1] "Kolkata"
```

Comment: Each city name should be come at 1st index.

Comment: @JayshreeSonawane not clear what you meant but you can see my update

Answer (score 0):

Use stringr

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(address_list, '\\w+$')
[1] "Mumbai"  "Delhi"   "Chennai" "Kolkata"
```